# using rspec to test that a URL exists for a sinatra app

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, routes, sinatra

I'm trying to link my people_controller.rb file with my index.erb file so that a user can click on a name from the /people page and go to a unique page through the people/:id route. This works in the browser, but the app keeps failing the spec test I was given. I'm thinking the spec file I was given is incorrect and isn't actually testing for the existence of the link.

This is my people_controller.rb file:

```
get "/people" do
    @people = Person.all

    erb :"/people/index"
end

get "/people/:id" do
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    birthdate_string = @person.birthdate.strftime("%m%d%Y")
    birth_path_num = Person.get_birth_path_num(birthdate_string)
    @message = Person.get_message(birth_path_num)

    erb :"/people/show"
end
```

This is my index.erb file:

```
<h1>People</h1>

<table>

    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birthdate</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% @people.each do |person| %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="<%="people/#{person.id}" %>">
                        <%= "#{person.first_name} #{person.last_name}" %>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= "#{person.birthdate}" %> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This is my spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Our Person Index Route" do
  include SpecHelper

  before (:all) do
    @person = Person.create(first_name: "Miss", last_name: "Piggy", birthdate: DateTime.now - 40.years )
  end

  after (:all) do
    @person.delete
  end

  it "displays a link to a person's show page on the index view" do
    get("/people")
    expect(last_response.body.include?("/people/#{@person.id}")).to be(true)
  end
end
```

This is the failure message I get when I try to run rspec with the spec file:

```
Failure/Error: expect(last_response.body.include?("/people/#{@person.id}")).to be(true)
expected true
got false
#  ./spec/people_show_link_spec.rb:16:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is that expect method actually checking for the existence of the link or only checking to see if there is a text string "/people/#{@person.id}" on the people page? Shouldn't it include "a href" in some way (or some other keyword indicating a link) if it is actually checking for the link?

Answer (score 0):

It only checks that there is the text string "/people/#{@person.id}".

A better expectation might be:

```
expect( page ).to have_css "a[href='/people/#{@person.id}']"
```

or

```
expect( page ).to have_link "#{person.first_name} #{person.last_name}"
```

Comment: The command terminal says that page is an undefined local variable. @page doesn't work either since that isn't defined in any of the files. Do you have a doc or resource referencing .to have_css or .to have_link methods? I haven't seen them referenced for rspec. I think I might need to use a redirect method in some way, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I should note that I don't have Capybara. I think .to have_css and .to_have link are methods for Capybara, but I only have Sinatra.

Comment: Capybara works with Sinatra. If you want to do things like check HTML nodes, then you probably want to use it.  You may need to configure RSpec to work with both Rack Test and Capybara:

Comment: This is for a Ruby on Rails class and the above spec is supposed to work as-is without Capybara. Capybara does seem like the easiest way to get the spec to work, but I would really be interested to see if there is a way to rewrite the spec without it so it's checking that the link exists.

Comment: You do have other options. You can check for the exact HTML string, use a regex, or use Nokogiri to parse the response. Capyabara is better than those 3 options.

Comment: Checking for the exact HTML string sounds more like what I'm trying to do here. I'm calling the page using sinatra and localhost though. I keep feeling like I need to involve redirect in some way like the code here: http://www.getlaura.com/how-to-test-a-sinatra-app-with-rspec/. However, those only check one step get methods and it feels like I need to do something else here to get rspec to check that the link exists and that it is connected to the name text.

Comment: Hmm...I do have the rack gem installed and last_response is an attribute of rack. I changed the line to last_response.match("/people/#{@person.id}") and that produced a successful test but I'm not sure if that's actually checking the link. I'm also not sure why that produces a successful test. Isn't the match method also just checking the text string and not the URL there?

Comment: Solved! It was a really dumb error. The spec actually can does check for the URL string in the link, it was just that I put "people/#{person.id}" instead of "/people/#{person.id}" like in the spec. So the links would still work correctly, but they would still fail the spec.